# Which dependencies are required to import `io.mockk.every` when writing Kotlin tests with Mockk?

Tags: mockk

I'm trying to write a test based on just `testCompile group: 'io.mockk', name: 'mockk', version: '1.7.15'` but in the code below:

```
import io.mockk.every
import io.mockk.any
import io.mockk.Runs
import io.mockk.impl.annotations.MockK
import io.mockk.junit5.MockKExtension

@ExtendWith(MockKExtension::class)
@TestInstance(TestInstance.Lifecycle.PER_CLASS)
internal class ConfigDistributorTest {
        @MockK
        lateinit var configService: ...

        @MockK
        lateinit var centralisedConfigRegisterService: ...

            val configDistributor =  ConfigDistributor(centralisedConfigRegisterService, configService)

            @Test
            fun shouldDistributeConfigToComponents(){
                every {
                    configService.readConfig(any())
                } just Runs
            }
        }
```

although `Runs`, `MockK` and `MockKExtension` are successfully imported,
the `every` and `any()` are not available. Is `io.mockk.any` the correct import statement and which other dependency is required to use them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First you need to import `every`. `import io.mockk.every` is the correct way to do it. Inside of `every` `any` is automatically imported, so you don't need to do that. Other things looks fine

Please invalidates caches, re-import project. Probably you have some issues with IDE.

Comment: We're using https://bazel.build as our build system and its our own project I'm trying to use `io.mock` in. It's possible that we're not adding the right jars to the classpath. Could you confirm that we only need mockk-1.7.15.jar, mockk-dsl-jvm-1.7.15.jar and mockk-agent-1.7.15.jar on the classpath ?

Comment: I can confirm that this is what I have in Gradle. +dependency kotlin-reflect

Comment: Thanks: it look like its some strange Intellij/Kotlin situation: in a java class, `import static io.mockk.MockKKt.every;` is fine!

Comment: Its sorted out now, thanks. It was an issue with how Kotlin dependencies are setup by `Bazel`. I'll be able to start using `io.mockk` properly now!